# Visitors who visited a certain URL

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

In Google Analytics, how to focus on visitors who visited a certain URL at least once?

Example:

- let's say UserA has visited http://example.com/purchasecompleted/SX8DQ/ on June 12th
- UserB has visited the same URL on June 10th.

**How to see all traffic of all time  (and be able to see referrers, etc.) of these visitors?**

This would allow to know where do the customers first came from (even if they first visited the website 10 days before buying)

---

*Note: When I'm in the this section :*

[image]

*I don't find an UI element to filter visitors who have visited a certain URL.*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to coding in any way. This should be posted to Webmasters instead.

Comment: @nyuen I think I need google analytics API, thus coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question on how to check all traffic to a given URL in Google Analytics, the best approach is for you to use a custom segment. You can do this by going to the top of the reports section and clicking on "+ Add Segment". Then you would be given the option to add a new segment, check the screenshot below for an example,

[image]

The second part of your question about the option to check the page URL in the Referrals report, you can use the secondary dimension "Page" to get this data. Refer to the image below,
[image]

However I wish to clarify that the Google Analytics Web UI doesn't provide hit level data, therefore you cannot get the stats about hit level custom dimensions and metrics which were sent to a particular page by a particular visitor. This could only be obtained if you've an Analytics 360 Premium account. Nevertheless, the data which you would get otherwise would be session level data (i.e. anyone who visited that URL along with all other URLs visited in that session)